# Rule for generating sequential numbers in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a google sheet in which each row is assigned a row followed by a unique label with a letter followed by a 4-digit number. The letter is based on the primary language selected for that row (language is another column). For example, the first Arabic speaker would be A0001, the first Farsi speaker F0001. At the moment these numbers are entered manually. Does anyone have a formula that would automatically generate these labels when the rows are created?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your sheet? Moreover, what have you tried in order to achieve this? @Bjb5xt

Answer (score 1):

There isn't all that much to go on in the question, but something like this may work for you:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",left(A2:A,1)&text(countifs(row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A),left(A2:A,1),left(A2:A,1)),"0000")))
```

Of course if any of the languages start with the same letter, it won't work!

[image]